# Filtering works on search page and doesn't on category product list

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, layered-navigation, filter, search

I am working on a Magento store and edit the code of another programmer. Now I runned in a problem. Filtering from layered navigation works on the search page and doesn't work on the page with products of a category.

Description:
Let's say I have category Shoes, with the attribute `Color`. 2 Products

- `Allure A302M`, white color
- `Allure 212M`, black color

If I search `Allure`, it finds those products. When filtering `white color` it finds `A302M` model. So Filter on search works. Now if I open `category shoes` and choose white color, filtering doesn't work, it find all shoes.

I found a custom module in `code/local` and removed it, but no change. What can be the problem? Maybe attribute configuration is wrong?

Configuration:

[image: Atribute properties]

[image: Frontend properties]

Comment: Maybe all your shoes have a white simple product associated?

Comment: No, there aren't. I have checked! And it doesn't work on any filter.

Comment: I don't know what the module you had was, but I ran into similar issues using lesti full page cache extension. filterable attributes needed to be defined in the config. But I'm assuming you flushed the cache after deleting and it still don't work?

Comment: @willboudle, Cache is disabled. Is there a way to find what functions are called for filtering or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it working. Don't know if this is a problem specific to this case or of Magento, but it worked after I changed the category value 'Is anchor' to yes.

Comment: Oh i thought Layered navigation was visible just not filtering. Yes that is the purpose of "is anchor" http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/anchor-categories